# Regression: user defined function

Tags: r, function, regression

This is a simple linear regression function for calculating beta values , residuals and fitted values. How can i add  more than one predictor to this function?

```
regression=function(x,y){
 x=cbind(1,x)
 beta=solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y
 residuals=y-x%*%beta
 fitted.values=x%*%beta
 res=list(coefficients=beta,residuals=residuals,fitted.values=fitted.values)
 class(res)="regression" 
 return(res)
}
```

Comment: By changing ```x``` you can add more predictors. Here ```x``` is a matrix so adding predictors means adding more columns.

Comment: i tried to pass a list (of predictors) as the first argument i.e  x here. It is throwing an error.

Comment: Pass ```x``` as a matrix and it would work. Give a reproducible example and that would help.

Comment: @AGore how can i add interaction terms in the function?

Comment: Use a `formula` and `model.matrix`. For a nice example, see `lm`.